# Ubuntu has been removed but still shows up in boot menu

Tags: boot, windows-7, menu

I installed Ubuntu as a dual-boot with my Windows 7 PC and then later removed Ubuntu (by deleting the partition and also by clicking 'Uninstall Ubuntu' in the Windows 7 control panel).

However when the PC boots up, it gives the option for Ubuntu, even though it should be removed. I want my PC to be a single Windows 7 boot again with no trace of Ubuntu and that automatically boots up to Windows 7 and would greatly appreciated someone who knows what they're doing's help with this please.

Thank you in advance,

David

Comment: @qbi a wubi install uses the windows bootloader. So, IMO, this is not a duplicate of the link you gave.

Comment: @David - I have had to delete your "answer" - you should edit your original question above by logging into your original account.  If you have lost access to this, please register your account, then click the link at the bottom of the page and ask for your unregistered and registered account to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

> In Windows XP you need to edit C:\boot.ini and delete the Ubuntu/Wubi line.
>
> Alternatively you can modify the boot menu via Control Panel > System > Advanced > Startup and Recovery and pressing "Edit".
>
> For Windows 98 you have to edit C:\config.sys and remove the Wubi block.
>
> For Windows Vista/7, you can use the built-in bcdedit command or install EasyBCD to edit the boot menu. To use bcdedit, run cmd.exe as an administrator, then enter bcdedit to show all boot entries, note the {GUID} specified for the Ubuntu entry, and then remove it: `bcdedit /delete {GUID}`

See also:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_manually_uninstall_Wubi.3F

Answer (score 1):

You can just press "start", then in the run box type "msconfig" then under the "boot" tab, delete Ubuntu.  Much easier that way :)

Comment: I am not familiar with windows, for what version(s) does that command `msconfig` work? Perhaps update the wubi FAQ page (it is a wiki and community maintained).

Comment: Windows xp and beyond that I know of. Not sure about before.